# Javascript not reloading page when using location.replace a second time with the same URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using `location.replace` to reload a page that uses GET variables for a success message.

My problem is, if the URL in the `location.replace` is exactly the same the page does not reload. I know that if I can use a condition and use `location.reload()` this will answer my question by I do not know how to use an IF statement on a `location.replace`, or any other way this could be done.

So when calling the `location.replace('?success=1');` whilst `?success=1` is already in the URL the page does not reload.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: In which browser are you experiencing the issue? The following works fine in Firefox 14/Chrome 20: `location.replace(location.href);` (via console). The only case where the page is not refreshed is when the URL contains a URL fragment (`#`).

Comment: Hi, Yes I am also using a `#` in the URL to anchor the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(window.location.href.match(/[?]success=1/))
    window.location.reload();
    else
    window.location.replace('?success=1')
```